# How to make some buttons call methods from previous classes in tkinter?

Tags: python, class, methods, tkinter

I used tkinter to set up 4 buttons, and I want to print different strings at each button press. When I run my code, I got 4  different strings printed(one of each) at once without pressing any of them and when I really press, nothing happens.
Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class motor:
    def __init__(eleMesmo, eixo , valorZero):
        eleMesmo.eixo = eixo
        eleMesmo.zero = valorZero

    def aumenta(self):
        print(self.eixo + str(self.zero+5))
def diminui(self):
        print(self.eixo + str(self.zero-5))
def para(self):
        print(self.eixo + str(self.zero))

def paraTudo():
    motor.para(eixox)
    motor.para(eixoy)

eixox = motor('x',90)
eixoy = motor('y',90)


class Interface:
    def __init__(elemesmo, widget):
        quadro = Frame(widget)
        quadro.pack()
        elemesmo.aumentarX = Button(quadro,text="Aumentar X",height=10,width=20,command=eixox.aumenta())
        elemesmo.aumentarX.pack(side=RIGHT)
        elemesmo.diminuirX = Button(quadro,text="Diminuir X",height=10,width=20,command=eixox.diminui())
        elemesmo.diminuirX.pack(side=LEFT)
        elemesmo.aumentarY = Button(quadro,text="Aumentar Y",height=10,width=20,command=eixoy.aumenta())
        elemesmo.aumentarY.pack(side=TOP)
        elemesmo.diminuirY = Button(quadro,text="Diminuir Y",height=10,width=20,command=eixoy.diminui())
        elemesmo.diminuirY.pack(side=TOP)

widget = Tk()
app = Interface(widget)
widget.mainloop()
```

Also, I would like to run `paraTudo()` when a button is released, independently which button was released, but I only know the `command` option.

Comment: remove `()` for all your methods in `command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions are being called as soon as the `Button` widgets are created.

```
...command=eixox.aumenta())
                        ^^
```

Including the parentheses calls the function and binds the `command` to the *returned result* of that function. You don't want that. You want to give the `Button` an actual function. It will call that function when you click it.

```
...command=eixox.aumenta)
```

Comment: And how can I call a function when a button is released? Thanks in advance